# Clear API errors [UWP]

Tags: api, service, error-handling, uwp, controller

I have a problem with my API, the GET, POST, DELETE and PUT work perfectly. but if for some reason at the time of making a PUT or a POST I generate errors (404, 400, 500, etc) and it is normal that in some times for any query I generate errors ... the problem is that the next Once I go back to do a POST or PUT (being aware that it is ok) the error is stored and it does not let me make the new query ... I do not know what to do or what is wrong. **but the GET is still working**

THIS IS THE CONTROLLER CODE:

```
  [HttpGet("{id}")] //GET
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long id)
  {
     if (id == 0)
     return BadRequest();
     var tercero = await repository.GetAsync(id);
     if (tercero == null)
        return NotFound();
     else
        return Ok(tercero);
   }

   [HttpPost] //POST
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Tercero tercero)
   {
     try
     {
         return Ok(await repository.InsertAsync(tercero));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         return BadRequest(e.ToString());
     }
   }

   [HttpPut("{id}")] //PUT
   public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]Tercero tercero, long Id)
   {
      if (tercero.Id != Id)
        return BadRequest("No hay correlacion entre el id y el objeto");

      try
      {
          return Ok(await repository.UpdateAsync(tercero, Id));
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           return BadRequest(e.ToString());
      }
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")] //DELETE
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(long id)
    {
      try
      {
          await repository.DeleteAsync(id);
          return Ok();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          return BadRequest(e.ToString());
      }
    }
```

I have other controllers and with all the same thing happens. I do not know if he finds something to clean up the error

***THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS***

STEP 1:
I do a POST with a new User

*It returns the model of the query with a 200 OK*

[image: It returns the model of the query with a 200 OK]

STEP 2: 
I generate an error giving the same code in one of the fields what the database does not allow me.

*It shows me the error with a 400 Bad Request*

[image]

STEP 3: I realize my mistake and I decide to correct it to make a correct POST

*It gives me the same error*

[image]

**WHY? How can i fix it?**

Comment: From the error message, the problem is you could not insert data with duplicate key, please try to remove the object contain duplicate key first, then post new one or use `PUT` method.

Comment: Is it possible that there is duplicate `codigo` property in the JSON? Could you debug the web service to see what is received? Also - try to use Fiddler to see the actual data being sent from your PC to the service.

Comment: I`m use Postman. its same?

Comment: Postman sends the request but Fiddler shows what was actually sent. So I would start there. Also - you can remotely debug the service or set up logging to see what was received on service's end