# is it possible to clean the cache of a service? [UWP]

Tags: c#, api, caching, uwp

I'm doing an application in UWP and since I'm managing a connection to a service in Azure that points to a database ... but I have this problem that saves me a previous error:

[Clear API errors [UWP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487383/clear-api-errors-uwp?noredirect=1#comment91921243_52487383)

So it occurred to me that maybe that error is being stored in the service cache. and I do not know, is it possible to clean the cache of a service? or clean the cache somewhere in the controller so that this error is not stored.

I have looked at this documentation but I still do not know how to implement it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edfcywt6.aspx

[How can I programmatically clear cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757733/how-can-i-programmatically-clear-cache)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/302329/How-to-force-clear-cache-in-asp-net

Comment: Is it possible you have OutputCache set up in your ASP. NET app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Martin Zikmund said, you'd better manage the outputcache in server side. If you want turn off the cache of httpclient, you could try this.

```
var RootFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

RootFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
RootFilter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

var HttpClient = new HttpClient(RootFilter);
```